# Why is \textvisiblespace represented by a rectangle?

Tags: fonts, xetex, symbols

I use xelatex, with Ubuntu font, and for some reason I can't insert a `\textvisiblespace` into my document - all that I get in result is a box: ``. Is there some way to fix that?

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ubuntu}
\begin{document}
\textvisiblespace
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\textvisiblespace` does not use any fonts. It constructs the "space character" as 3 rules. What kind of warnings do you receive in your output/`.log` file?

Comment: @Werner - seems that it is not true - since the `.log` file contains this line: `Missing character: There is no ␣ in font Ubuntu/ICU:mapping=tex-text,!`. But I would be more than happy to draw it using three rules. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I've referenced a possible solution. It should work in your instance, but I'm unable to test it since I don't have the fonts installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font `Ubuntu` doesn't support the Unicode character 2423. Use

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{DejaVu Serif}
```

for example. Another alternative maybe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ubuntu}
\newfontface\TVSp{DejaVu Serif}
\def\textvisiblespace{{\TVSp\char"2423}}

\begin{document}
\textvisiblespace
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's sad, I like that font. But maybe you can suggest more conventional font? I'm writing a technical documentation text, that would be probably read on computer screen.

Comment: see edited answer. However, `Ubuntu` is similiar to `Bera Sans`

Comment: +1, but I suggest `\protected\def`. It's true that `\TVSp` will be "robust", but it's perhaps more desirable to write `\textvisiblespace` in case it appears in a moving argument.

Comment: And where is the problem, if it appears for example in a `\caption` command??

Answer (score 4):

I don't have the font installed, so I'm not sure whether this is what you're after:

1. Redefine `\textvisiblespace` after loading the Ubuntu font. The following definition is taken from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

   ```
   \def\textvisiblespace{%
      \mbox{\kern.06em\vrule height.3ex}%
      \vbox{\hrule width.3em}%
      \hbox{\vrule height.3ex}}
   ```
2. Capture the contents of `\textvisiblespace` in a box *before* loading the new font and restore it afterwards:

   ```
   % Document preamble
   \newsavebox{\textvisiblespacebox}
   \begin{lrbox}{\textvisiblespacebox}\textvisiblespace\end{lrbox}
   % Insert font-related changes here
   \def\textvisiblespace{\usebox{\textvisiblespacebox}}
   ```

   Note that this will fix the setting of `\textvisiblespace` in `\normalfont`, so it won't change with size changes like `\small` (for example).